# Django model relationships make avg ratings be an average of ratings number field

Tags: django, model, relationship

So I have two Django Models 'Movie' and 'Rating' i want the Movie field avg_rating to be an average of the ratings belonging to that movies number field. I also want the avg_rating on the movie field to update every time a review is added. Im new to Django so I don't really know where to start. Below is my models file. any help would be appreciated

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import IntegerField, Model
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator


class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateField()
    image = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    details = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    classification = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    avg_rating = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        default=1,
        validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(5),
            MinValueValidator(0)
        ]
    )
    

class Rating(models.Model):

    number = models.IntegerField(
        default=1,
        validators=[
            MaxValueValidator(5),
            MinValueValidator(0)
        ]
    )
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way is to define a method in your `Movie` class to return the average rating of your `Movie` object. So you just have to add the following code in your model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce
from django.db.models import IntegerField, Model
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator


class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateField()
    image = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    details = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    classification = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    def rating_avg(self):
        return Rating.objects.filter(movie=self).aggregate(
                avg=Coalesce(models.Avg('number'), 0),
            )['avg']
```

Note that the field rating average is removed from `Movie` fields. Now you have a method that you can call it per `Movie` object and this method will return you an average rating for that object at specific time.

Example:

```
movie_object = Movie.objects.first()
if movie_object:
    print(movie_object.rating_avg()) # will print average rating of that particular object
```

And if you're using a `Serializer` or a `ModelForm` for `Movie` model you can also add that method's name to fields of that `Serializer` or `ModelForm` to calculate average rating per object whenever you call a view on this object (i.e. `fields = ['title', ..., 'rating_avg']`).